# NameError: name 'FaceDetector' is not defined

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, face-detection

I was trying to run this code but it says

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-49e303967177> in <module>
      3 
      4 #Detector object created
----> 5 fd=FaceDetector(frontal_cascade_path)

NameError: name 'FaceDetector' is not defined
```

This is the code: -

```
#Frontal face of haar cascade loaded
frontal_cascade_path="../input/haarcascade-frontal-faces/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"

#Detector object created
fd=FaceDetector(frontal_cascade_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://pypi.org/project/face-detector/). You need to import the `FaceDetector` into your code:

```py
from face_detector import FaceDetector
```

Comment: I tried importing the package but it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'face_detector'`

Comment: Did you install the package?

Comment: Then you should `pip install face-detector`

Comment: I tried but it did not work, there was a error. Now I am trying to use a different package `import cv2`